# Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx): Take action once all events are completed

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

As a proof of concept, I want to write "Done" in a text box *after* a check box has been checked and a key has been pressed in a text box (in either order). I would expect this code to handle this, but it writes Done as soon as either event happens. Thanks for your help.

```
var seq = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(this.checkBox, "CheckedChanged")
   .Merge(Observable.FromEvent<KeyPressEventArgs>(this.textBox, "KeyPress"));

seq.Subscribe((unused) => this.resultTextBox.Text = "Done");
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use Observable.When like so (I've added an additional CheckBox for this example):

```
var checkChanged  = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(this.checkBox, "CheckedChanged");
var check1Changed = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(this.checkBox1, "CheckedChanged");
var keyPress      = Observable.FromEvent<KeyPressEventArgs>(this.textBox, "KeyPress");

var plan1 = checkChanged
            .And(check1Changed).And(keyPress)
            .Then((cc, cc1, kp) => "Done.");

var when = Observable.When(plan1);

when.Subscribe((result) => this.resultTextBox.Text = result);
```

Also, if you can join other plans together, for example if things can be "done" when either one set of events fire, or also when another set of events fire:

```
var checkChanged  = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(this.checkBox, "CheckedChanged");
var check1Changed = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(this.checkBox1, "CheckedChanged");
var keyPress      = Observable.FromEvent<KeyPressEventArgs>(this.textBox, "KeyPress");
var keyPress1     = Observable.FromEvent<KeyPressEventArgs>(this.textBox1, "KeyPress");

var plan1 = checkChanged.And(check1Changed).And(keyPress).Then((cc, cc1, kp) => "Done.");
var plan2 = keyPress.And(keyPress1).Then((kp, kp1) => "Alternate done.");

var join = Observable.When(plan1, plan2);
```

Comment: Thanks - I toyed with this approach as well. If these events were async. network calls, would you prefer this style over the Zip approach?

Comment: I like that. Is handling an error condition in one of these events a trivial matter?

Comment: I haven't tried doing this with Zip, btw.  Maybe I'll try it later to compare.

Comment: Handle errors via the Subscribe overload that takes an OnError Action.  e.g.:  join.Subscribe((result) => this.resultTextBox.Text = result, ex => Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message));

Answer (score 1):

if you need both events to happen - consider using Zip. Merge will trigger the event if **any** of merged sources raise it.

Comment: What if there were 10 different events, instead of two?

Comment: Zip returns Observable that will trigger events when both sources raise it (like rendezvous). You can Zip this result Observable with another one to obtain Observable connected to 3 sources etc...

Comment: Would that be a reasonable approach? What about using Observable.Join with Ands?