# I am trying to write a filter for choices made with buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to c# with linq and I am trying to figure out how to do multiple filtering selection with buttons.

I am connected to a database,
I have `enum stats{approved, rejected, pending approval, pending rejected, cancelled};`

A `IEnumerator` type List, how do I do in such a way that the code can be more manageable as one can keep adding N number of choices in the future and it will still work rather than using `if else or switch cases` to hard code all possible cases.

e.g.

```
if(stats contains approve)
List = List.dbset.where(x => x.id.stats == approved);
```

`//return the view that displays all the list of things with stats approved.`

Am not sure how am I going to combine it into a loop. Require some assistance.

Desired output is I can select 2 or more buttons and the list returns those selected filter values element out.

Comment: You can create a list of values selected by the buttons and then use the list in query as `List.dbset.where(x => choices.Containts(x.id.stats));` here `choices` is the collection of values selected by buttons.

Comment: @Bonbon, first of all don't use `enum` if you want to manage `stats`.  I would suggest create another `object` `(class)` to define your `stats` with properties.  The `stats` object should query from a database which contains all your stats and retrieve the records via `LINQ`.  For example `IList<stats> statList = new List<stats>();`  You can loop through from the `statList object` and do your logic there.

Comment: I'll give it a try! Thanks!

Comment: It is easy i linq to do x.stats = myVariable. Its hard to do x.(unknown) = y.unknown.  If you are trying to do something like that you will need to build up the query dynamically using something like a predicate builder. I hope that helps

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for Join patterns here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3868608/13131

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have the choices already but due to the type I cannot use the contains method.

Comment: @Juniuz there is no need for another object class since I can loop through enums too.

Comment: @JKerny I already have some ways to get the filter but not sure how to combine them to make it flexible for any amounts of filtering buttons selected. I have a hashset that contains the stats, I have a List of application list that I can simply do x => x.stats.Equals(stats.cancelled) something like that.

Comment: @RichardAnthonyHein thanks for the suggestion but join patterns are not what I am looking for.

Comment: add `using System.Linq;` at the top of of your class file. What is the type of `choices` variable? What is the type of `x.id.stats` ?

Comment: type of choices is enum and x.id.stats is also enum lol basically I am trying to filter with the enums given. So there is no point to make extra stuff to go about it.
Either I try to find a way to combine different base case list into 1 and output it or I try to loop the list, if stats == approved i add to a list, and if more stats are selected then keep adding them to the list and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so actually the problem is because the return views always return the list with everything despite multiple filtering. All I did was create a new displaylist and union every filtered list when filter is applied and return that displaylist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can develop a filter method it like this, than can send some values to filter ;

```
List<yourType> filteredList = dbset.ToList();
if(stats1 contains approve){
    List<yourType> filteredList = filteredList.where(x => 
x.id.stats==approved).ToList();
}
if(stats2 contains approve){
    List<yourType> filteredList = filteredList.where(x => 
x.id.stats==approved).ToList();
}
return filteredList;
```

Comment: I already have something like this, I have currently 5 List.
1 List that contains everything.
1 List that filters out each type of stats individually.
I am trying to see how I can combine them all.

The idea is that I am trying to combine my list into 1 list to display the output
for example I selected stat 1 and 2, then I union list1 and list2 and output the list.

Maybe I am restricting myself too much since the source code is not by me and I am tasked to implement new things with it so I guess I have to ask what can I touch and not touch.

Comment: All of lists are the same type  ? if theese are the same type , you can addRange all choosed lists to filteredList variable to response ?